# Determine page content based on page parent

Tags: pages, page-template, conditional-content, hierarchical

How can I display a gallery shortcode for pages who are children of the page with an ID of 9, and the regular content for pages who aren't? This is what I've tried so far, but it's not working:

```
<?php global $wp_query; if( (9 == $ $wp_query->post->post_parent ) :?>
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery link="file" columns="1" size="large"]'); ?>
<?php else (); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$thispageid = get_the_ID();
$thispageparent = get_ancestors($thispageid);
if( in_array( 9, $thispageparent ) )
     echo do_shortcode('[gallery link="file" columns="1" size="large"]'); 
else
    the_content();
```

reference [get_ancestors()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors)

Comment: Should there be something at the end to close this? 
Gives an error, says a problem with the line where I have 
`<?php get_footer(); ?>`

Comment: changed the code a bit. notice `$thispageparent = get_ancestors($thispageid);`

Comment: also, you've commented on the response above, but i think you meant to write it here :)

Comment: Hi Peteroak, thanks for your help. Reply above was for NVWD, was trying out both solutions :)

I switched the shortcode and the_content and it worked for the parent page (shows the_content OK), but the gallery on the child page isn't working. It's the shortcode part.

Just to make sure I switched everything around correctly, here's the code
`<?php
     $thispageid = get_the_ID();
     $thispageparent = get_ancestors($thispageid);
     if( $thispageparent[0] == 9 )   
       echo the_content();
     else
      do_shortcode('[gallery link="file" columns="1" size="large"]');
?>`

Comment: Ahhh added "echo" before the shortcode bit. Thanks a lot! Your solution is working.

Comment: glad its working for you! please mark this as the correct answer. thanks!

Comment: How do I accept an answer? By voting up? It won't let me do it until I have reputation of 15+.

Comment: hover over the left side part, and a green check will appear. thanks!

Comment: Since `$thispageparent` is an array, you should use something like `if( in_array( 9, $thispageparent ) )`. Otherwise the condition could return false if 9 is at a different index in the array. That's not likely with standard pages, but could happen if they were customized to allow multiple parents.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php global $wp_query; if ( 9 == $wp_query->post->post_parent ) : ?>
    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[gallery link="file" columns="1" size="large"]' ); ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
```

Comment: Gives an error, says a problem with this line:
`'object_id'   => $thispageid, `